# Load balancing multiple internet connections

Tags: routing, load-balancing, internet

I've got the following scenario:
- one low speed and low latency DSL connection (cable) (250kb/s 25ms)
- one high speed and high latency DSl connection (satellite) (1250kb/s ~1500ms)

Is there a possibility to automatically route file downloads (over a certain size or in general) over the high speed connection while keeping the normal traffic routed over the low latency connection?

Comment: I can't imagine a feasible solution to this. You won't be able to know the file size until you actually starts downloading it.

Comment: It'd be much easier to setup a failover scenario, where everything runs across the High speed connection unless it's not available.  Many business class routers already support this functionality as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a lot easier to up-pref certain things on the low latency connection and allow everything else to go on the high latency connection.  For example, send the VoIP traffic on the low latency connection.  As far as file transfers, some protocols send the file size in the beginning (http on some downloads), but this information is pretty high up in the protocol stack, and you would need a correspondingly sophisticated "router" to make this decision.  In short, what you're asking for is not any kind of commercial off the shelf product, and it would require substantial effort from you to get this accomplished.